# Xamarin forms template switch native content remains

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am seeing something strange where an instance of ContentView from a ControlTemplate affects how another instance of the ContentView looks, under the same page, from another ControlTemplate.

ContentView BLA:

```
ScrollView
L Accordion control
  L Accordion Item
```

Control template A:

```
BLA
```

Control template B:

```
Tab control
L Tab 1 Content: BLA
L Tab 2 Content: other
```

Somehow switching ControlTemplate from A to B, B to A,

And the height of the accordion item remain from the first template.

It is not the same instance.

How can I make sure the native controls are disposed of when switching ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved away from template switching as the template is being cached, meaning the last view is still in memory, and this causes all kind of problems such as binding errors and layout measures turning out wrong.

I now use MyView which inherits ContentView:

```
public class MyView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(MyView ), null, propertyChanging: OnDataPropertyChanging);
    public object Data
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(DataProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnDataPropertyChanging(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var instance = bindable as MyViewModel;
        instance.Content = null;
        if (newValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var type = newValue.GetType();
        View view = null;
        if (type == typeof(MyViewModel1))
        {
            view = new BLA();
        }
        else if (type == typeof(MyViewModel2))
        {
            view = new other();
        }
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.BindingContext = newValue;
            instance.Content = view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we use `DataTemplateSelector` to switch templates.

For the Limitations in the MSdocs, the warnings, however the reason behind it, is due to the caching of templates in the renderer. If you change it up, the previous template will be cached in the renderer and there will be no longer any way to reference or dispose of it, until the ListView is disposed of. Hence as you scroll, it will continue to cache new templates and never free up the old ones.

Hope this would be helpful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I have a few questions: 
If I have a renderer for BLA, can I prevent its caching?
Maybe I can cancel the caching of the control templates, in xaml or otherwise?
Is there a time limit for how long a renderer keeps in cache the template?
If I see BLA renderer hits the Dispose() method, is the renderer still alive after that, its cache included?

Comment: Currently there is no other way, this is the default limitations.